# I defined just one php docker, but when I run docker-compose down many php dockers stoped

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Look at this picture:
After running docker-compose and work about 1 hour then PHP print all posted data in response and when I stop docker-compose many PHP containers as you see in the picture stopped many PHP dockers with random id.

I think that's not normal. have you a solution for this problem?

[image: docker]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The additional containers you are seeing here are the ones created by [`docker-compose run`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/run/) which always creates a new container.

If you need to run different commands in your containers and don't want to have them pile up you could:

- `docker-compose run --rm` to automatically delete the new containers as soon as they exit
- re-use a previous container with e.g. [`docker start -ti docker_php_run_e6bd6c5290c`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/start/)
- use [`docker-compose exec`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/) to execute a command in the running service container

Or you could just ignore the additional containers. The best solution of course depends on your use case.